# Configure external display on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, xorg, display

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Acer Aspire 5742Z and everythings working great except my external display. I've got an HP ZR2440w. The Display settings for this show it's running at its native 1920*1200 at 60hz but the image isn't at native resolution. Its stretched a little, both vertically and horizontally.

Is there a way I can automatically configure the external display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The monitor has an "Overscan" option in the menu under Image Control > Custom Scaling> Overscan which was set to Auto, changing this to Off displays the image correctly.